# force fileformat=unix when opening stdin in vim

Tags: vim

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/10280014/447503 they explain how to reopen a regular file with `fileformat=unix` to show `^M`s in it. It works on command line for regular files too:

```
$ vim -c "e ++ff=unix" aaa.txt
a^M
b^M
c^M
```

However, it fails when reading from stdin:

```
$ cat aaa.txt | vim -R -c "e ++ff=unix" -
Vim: Reading from stdin...
Error detected while processing command line:
E32: No file name
Press ENTER or type command to continue
a
b
c
```

It's because the command tells vim to re-read the currently open file. How to tell it to open the input with the desired fileformat from the start?

Comment: Is the main task to show the otherwise invisible characters? Would `cat -v` be enough to that end?

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps slightly stronger than opening the contents of stain with `ff=unix`... But you could enable binary-mode with the [`-b` command-line flag](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-b):

```
$ cat aaa.txt | vim -R -b -
```

See also [`:help 'binary'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27binary%27), which explains the `'binary'` option that implements this feature. (The `-b` command-line argument effectively enables this setting before the files passed as arguments are read.)

From `:help 'binary'`:

> Also, `'fileformat'` and `'fileformats'` options will not be used, the file is read and written like `'fileformat'` was "unix" (a single `<NL>` separates lines).

As you can see, that's in a way different from setting `ff=unix` but it has a very similar effect. Also, enabling `'binary'` has other side effects during editing, for instance to options such as `'textwidth'` and `'expandtab'`, but perhaps that's acceptable (or even desirable) to you in this case. Again, check `:help 'binary'` for full details. [`:help edit-binary`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#edit-binary) might be helpful too.